# Unit testing controller error. When I try to use the controller in the unit test, I get this error

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, unit-testing, .net-6.0

When I try to use the controller in the unit testing, I get this error. I am using MS Testing for the unit tests.

Testing code

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task PostDataReturnOk()
{
        var data = _fixture.Create<ProductCat>();
        _categoryRepository.Setup(re => re.AddCat(It.IsAny<ProductCat>())).Returns(data);
        _Controller = ProductCatsController(_Controller.Object);
}
```

[image: Testing Code]

Controller

```
public ProductCatsController(IProCatRepository repository, IMapper mapper)
{
    _ProCatService = repository;
    _mapper = mapper;
}
```

[image: Constructor]

```
[HttpPost]
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
public ActionResult<CategoryDto> CreateCategory(CreateCatDto Categ)
{
    var catEntity = _mapper.Map<ProductCat>(Categ);
    var NewCategory = _ProCatService.AddCat(catEntity);

    var CatForReturn = _mapper.Map<CategoryDto>(NewCategory);

    return CreatedAtRoute("GetCat", new { id = CatForReturn.Id }, CatForReturn);
}
```

Post method - this is what I need to test

[image: Post Method]

Comment: The formal parameter of the ProductCatsController method is null. Pass in the appropriate parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the new keyword.

```
_Controller = new ProductCatsController(_Controller.Object);
```

Further you need to pass in the relevant parameters for ProductCatsController constructor of the types `IProCatRepository repository, IMapper mapper`

Comment: can you explain how can i do it.